# Calling method from main throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I try to call the method `ss` from my `main` method, but it throws the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at teste1.exp.ss(exp.java:16)
        at teste1.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Java Result: 1
```

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] arguments) {
...................
    private static String[] ff;
    exp mega = new exp();
mega.ss(ff);

}

class exp {

 public void ss (String gvanswer[]){


    String answer[] = new String[3];

            answer[0] = "pacific ";
            answer[1] = "everest";
            answer[2] = "amazon ";

    if (gvnswer[0].equals("pacific"))
   {System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeee  ");}

  if (gvanswer[1].equals(answer[1])){System.out.println("l  ");}

    }
```

Comment: With class, function and variable names like that, I doubt dealing with NPE's will be your biggest problem in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

you call `mega.ss(ff)` but ff has never been initialited with somthing like:

```
ff = new String[1];
ff[0] = "foo";
```

Comment: typo when defining `String` array

Answer (score 0):

You haven't populated the the array called `ff` which you are passing into the `ss` method.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `ss` method an uninitialized `String[]` array (`ff`) hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Actually: he's not passing "an unitialized `String[]`", he's passing no `String[]` at all!